# Google Chart - stacked chart one data two filters

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Location    Company GR1     GR2 GR3 GR4 GR5

1   NYC     CUSTOMERS   0       0   13  5   19

2   CALI    ORG         270     210 0   32  51

3   CALI    CUSTOMERS   35.942  39  0   50  126

4   WDC     CUSTOMERS   0       0   35  52  88

5   WDC     CUSTOMERS   44.507  0   25  18  88

6   NJ      ORG         0       0   54  22  28

7   TXS     CUSTOMERS   0       0   0   10  11

Filter Location :
[NYC, CALI, WDC, NJ, TXS, UT, GA]

Filter Company :
[CUSTOMERS, ORG]

IN ColumnChart-STACKED for CALI and WDC it shows two columns. there i want to show as a single column of a cumulated value of both CUSTOMERS and ORG. but for table it s ok to show two CALI and WDC.

My Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
    drawMainDashboard();
});

function drawMainDashboard() {
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
document.getElementById('dashboard_division1'));

var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div',
'options': {
  'filterColumnIndex': 1,
  'ui': {
    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
    'label': 'Company Selection:',
    'allowTyping': false,
    'allowMultiple': false
  }
}
});

var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div1',
'options': {
  'filterColumnIndex': 0,
  'ui': {
    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
    'label': 'Location Selection:',
    'allowTyping': false,
    'allowMultiple': false
  }
}
});

var columnchrt = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
'containerId': 'chart_div',
'options': {
     title: "Locations  charts today",
     width: 850,
     height: 500,
     legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 2 },
     bar: { groupWidth: '70%' },
     isStacked: true,
     explorer: {keepInBounds: true, maxZoomIn: 10.0}
},
'view': {'columns': [0,2,3,4,5,7]}
});

var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
'chartType': 'Table',
'containerId': 'table_div',
'options': {
    showRowNumber: true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    allowHtml: true
},
'view': {'columns': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]}
});

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['Location', 'Company', 'Beverage', 'Food', 'Industrial', 'Un-Filled', 'Total', { role: 'annotation' } ],
 <c:forEach items="${GrsByCompanyList}" var="entry">
    [ '${entry.key}', '${entry.value7}', ${entry.value1}, ${entry.value2}, ${entry.value3}, ${entry.value4}, ${entry.value5}, ${entry.value6} ],
  </c:forEach>
]); 

dashboard.bind([categoryPicker,categoryPicker1], [columnchrt, table]);
dashboard.draw(data);
}

<div id="dashboard_division" style="clear:left; display:inline-block; width:100%; float:left; margin-top:5px;">

<div class="float_left panel" style="float:left; width:60%; padding:0px;">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="float_left panel" style="width:38%; padding:0px;">
    <div class="table_bbar" style="background-color:#27ae60;" >
        <h4>by Locations as on Today</h4>
        <div id="categoryPicker_div" style="right:15px; position:absolute;"></div>
        <div id="categoryPicker_div1" ></div>
    </div>

    <div id="table_div"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason there are two columns for CALI and WDC,
is because there are two rows in the data table.

in order to have one column, you need to aggregate the data table on location.

this could be performed by removing the chart from the dashboard,
then draw it separately when the table chart's `'ready'` event fires.
to do this, you need to remove the `view` from the column chart.

when the ready event fires, aggregate the data table.
you will also need to build a data view over the aggregated data table,
in order to add back the total annotation.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  drawMainDashboard();
});

function drawMainDashboard() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
  document.getElementById('dashboard_division1'));

  var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnIndex': 1,
    'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'label': 'Company Selection:',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  }
  });

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div1',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnIndex': 0,
    'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'label': 'Location Selection:',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  }
  });

  var columnchrt = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
  'containerId': 'chart_div',
  'options': {
       title: "Locations  charts today",
       width: 850,
       height: 500,
       legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 2 },
       bar: { groupWidth: '70%' },
       isStacked: true,
       explorer: {keepInBounds: true, maxZoomIn: 10.0}
  }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'Table',
  'containerId': 'table_div',
  'options': {
      showRowNumber: true,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      allowHtml: true
  },
  'view': {'columns': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]}
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    // get filtered data table from table chart
    var dt = table.getDataTable();

    // build aggregation and view columns
    var aggColumns = [];
    var viewColumns = [0];
    for (var i = 2; i < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      if (i !== dt.getNumberOfColumns() - 2) {
        if (dt.getColumnType(i) === 'number') {
          if (dt.getColumnRole(i) === 'annotation') {
            addAnnColumn(i);
          } else {
            addAggColumn(i);
            viewColumns.push(i - 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    function addAggColumn(index) {
      aggColumns.push({
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        column: index,
        label: dt.getColumnLabel(index),
        type: dt.getColumnType(index)
      });
    }
    function addAnnColumn(index) {
      viewColumns.push({
        calc: 'stringify',
        role: 'annotation',
        sourceColumn: aggColumns.length,
        type: 'string'
      });
    }

    // aggregate data table
    var agg = google.visualization.data.group(
      dt,
      [0],
      aggColumns
    );

    // create agg data view to add annotation
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(agg);
    view.setColumns(viewColumns);

    // draw chart
    columnchrt.setDataTable(view);
    columnchrt.draw();
  });


  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Location', 'Company', 'Beverage', 'Food', 'Industrial', 'Un-Filled', 'Total', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['NYC', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 13, 5, 19, 19],
    ['CALI', 'ORG', 270, 210, 0, 32, 51, 51],
    ['CALI', 'CUSTOMERS', 35.942, 39, 0, 50, 126, 126],
    ['WDC', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 35, 52, 88, 88],
    ['WDC', 'CUSTOMERS', 44.507, 0, 25, 18, 88, 88],
    ['NJ', 'ORG', 0, 0, 54, 22, 28, 28],
    ['TXS', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 0, 10, 11, 11]
  ]);

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker,categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_division" style="clear:left; display:inline-block; width:100%; float:left; margin-top:5px;">

<div class="float_left panel" style="float:left; width:60%; padding:0px;">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="float_left panel" style="width:38%; padding:0px;">
    <div class="table_bbar" style="background-color:#27ae60;" >
        <h4>by Locations as on Today</h4>
        <div id="categoryPicker_div" style="right:15px; position:absolute;"></div>
        <div id="categoryPicker_div1" ></div>
    </div>

    <div id="table_div"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

in the annotation columns, we'll need to manually calculate the total...

```
viewColumns.push({
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var c = 1; c < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
      total += dt.getValue(row, c);
    }
    return total.toFixed(0);
  },
  role: 'annotation',
  type: 'string'
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  drawMainDashboard();
});

function drawMainDashboard() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
  document.getElementById('dashboard_division1'));

  var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnIndex': 1,
    'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'label': 'Company Selection:',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  }
  });

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div1',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnIndex': 0,
    'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'label': 'Location Selection:',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  }
  });

  var columnchrt = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
  'containerId': 'chart_div',
  'options': {
       title: "Locations  charts today",
       width: 850,
       height: 500,
       legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 2 },
       bar: { groupWidth: '70%' },
       isStacked: true,
       explorer: {keepInBounds: true, maxZoomIn: 10.0}
  }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'Table',
  'containerId': 'table_div',
  'options': {
      showRowNumber: true,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      allowHtml: true
  },
  'view': {'columns': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]}
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    // get filtered data table from table chart
    var dt = table.getDataTable();

    // build aggregation and view columns
    var aggColumns = [];
    var viewColumns = [0];
    for (var i = 2; i < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      if (i !== dt.getNumberOfColumns() - 2) {
        if (dt.getColumnType(i) === 'number') {
          if (dt.getColumnRole(i) !== 'annotation') {
            addAggColumn(i);
            viewColumns.push(i - 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    function addAggColumn(index) {
      aggColumns.push({
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        column: index,
        label: dt.getColumnLabel(index),
        type: dt.getColumnType(index)
      });
    }

    // aggregate data table
    var agg = google.visualization.data.group(
      dt,
      [0],
      aggColumns
    );

    viewColumns.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        var total = 0;
        for (var c = 1; c < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
          total += dt.getValue(row, c);
        }
        return total.toFixed(0);
      },
      role: 'annotation',
      type: 'string'
    });

    // create agg data view to add annotation
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(agg);
    view.setColumns(viewColumns);

    // draw chart
    columnchrt.setDataTable(view);
    columnchrt.draw();
  });


  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Location', 'Company', 'Beverage', 'Food', 'Industrial', 'Un-Filled', 'Total', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['NYC', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 13, 5, 19, 19],
    ['CALI', 'ORG', 270, 210, 0, 32, 51, 51],
    ['CALI', 'CUSTOMERS', 35.942, 39, 0, 50, 126, 126],
    ['WDC', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 35, 52, 88, 88],
    ['WDC', 'CUSTOMERS', 44.507, 0, 25, 18, 88, 88],
    ['NJ', 'ORG', 0, 0, 54, 22, 28, 28],
    ['TXS', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 0, 10, 11, 11]
  ]);

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker,categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_division" style="clear:left; display:inline-block; width:100%; float:left; margin-top:5px;">

<div class="float_left panel" style="float:left; width:60%; padding:0px;">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="float_left panel" style="width:38%; padding:0px;">
    <div class="table_bbar" style="background-color:#27ae60;" >
        <h4>by Locations as on Today</h4>
        <div id="categoryPicker_div" style="right:15px; position:absolute;"></div>
        <div id="categoryPicker_div1" ></div>
    </div>

    <div id="table_div"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted... thanks your guide... one more to ask... i have 30 locations for xAxis lables but it displays 15 only other 15 goes below as hidden... how i display all of them... thanks

Comment: i got it done with this hAxes: {showTextEvery: 1, slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 45},

Comment: in your above is all ok. added i want not to display total values in COLUMN CHART. that should display only in table. in chart look i tried if (dt.getColumnLabel(i) === 'Total') { but this doent work....

Comment: total is excluded... but annotation is not coming...  can i get that total column as in annotation??? i tried this... dt.getNumberOfColumns()-1 but the Unfilled values coming as annotation... but need to bring total as in annotaiton

Comment: did you see that..., unfilled value is coming as annotation... but need Total value as a annotation...

Comment: yes, thanks. I have a solution, but it will take me a day or so to get to it. basically, you will need to manually set the value of the annotation using `calc: function()`, rather than `calc: 'stringify'`

Comment: i tried to changing the sourcecolumn number manually... but it accepts only the number columns in loop but annotation type is not accepts in source column. for ex: 1-4 is number column 5 is annotation... if i give 1-4 shows that column as annotation but if i give 5 shows error Invalid column index 5. Should be an integer in the range [0-4].  hope you get a sol. thanks

Comment: i tried this.. calc: function(dt, rowIndex) { return dt.getValue(rowIndex, 5).toString()}, but still same that 5 column is not shows as annotation... same error

Comment: Dear Mr.WhiteHat, is there any no of records limitations? well i can't able to list in table and in chart more than 50 records... goes empty table and chart. i have to display around 150 records in table as well as in Chart.

Comment: although it might not be legible with more than 50 records, there should not be a limit. sounds like there might be an error? have you checked the browser's console? (press F12 on most)

Comment: ya i got the error: it is in the string value... "[ 'W-3436','HENRY'S LABORATORIES, TXS', 'VZG', 'C-FG', 22.03, 24.97, 47, 47],"  there is a single quote in string. actually "Henry's Labora, TXS"... is a single column value... how do i fix this...

Comment: assuming there are no values with double quotes, when loading your data in the `forEach`, you could change the single quote to double quote, here --> `[ "${entry.key}", "${entry.value7}", ...` -- otherwise, you will need to replace the single quote with backslash single quote --> `\'`

Comment: yes. but i have done this process in java file itself by str replace method. works charm.
well can i have a setSelectedValues for the categoryFilter with allowTyping:true

Comment: not sure I follow the last question, but to set the selected values, use the `setState` method on the control...

Comment: Dear WhiteHat, for this same Post of google chart... how can i get and show the column wise total of Food, Beverage and Industrical Grades????